# OData security WCF data services Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

I am trying to setup an OData service using WCF Data Services with Entity Framework 6.

I created my service by inheriting from `EntityFrameworkDataService` which works fine for retrieving all data. I would like to add a security layer on top of my entities so that not all tables / fields are visible over the OData service.

I have tried the `QueryInterceptors` which work ok as far as limiting the table. It is not possible to return a limited entity (removing properties user does not have access to). The admin will decide which use has access to table and fields therefore I can not pre-create sub entities. There will be over 100 tables in the database so the solution needs to be generic.

I have also looked at [WCF Data Services ability to restrict returned fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069608/wcf-data-services-ability-to-restrict-returned-fields). However since I do not have `DataMember` / `DataContract` etc on my entities also no place to expose `OperationContract` either, this solution also does not fit.

Comment: Any reason you choose to use WCF? It is in maintained mode, and for new users, we recommend to use RESTier.

Comment: How can this be achieve in web api ? not set in stone to use wcf.

Comment: In Web Api odata 6.0.0, you can control the properties to be used for query options like select, expand and so on, you can refer to this link for more details. http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-01-modelbound-attribute

This also works in restier as restier using Web Api oData query validation logic.